# Server 2016 - no admin account can access non c: volumes

Tags: windows-server-2016

Basically, there are two volumes on the server e: and f: I have two domain admin accounts and the local admin account.  None of these accounts can access the volumes - access denied.

I tried using icacls and takeown from elevated cmd but both result in access denied.  I tried enabling gpo "user account control admin approval mode..." and rebooting server with no luck.  I tried disabling gpo "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" with no luck.

I have been all over this site and have googled this for 2 days with no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: Are the domain admin accounts granted local admin on the server (check Local Users and Groups and make sure the domain admin group is where it needs to be). Are the volumes OK, as in, have you tested them? Are they accessible for any other user? Does another user have ownership? Did these admin accounts have appropriate controls previously? If so, do you know what changed?

Comment: They do have local admin.  I figured out that the server is a Hyper-V host, and it looks like one of these is an external hdd and the other is a usb drive or sd card (searched by powershell and hardware id's from device manager).  Now I'm wondering if there is a hyper-v setting locking these down?

Comment: As these are both removable, permissions set by other systems in the past may be in play. Once again: Did they work on this system at some point in the past? If so, when did they work, and what has changed/happened since?

Comment: Unknown unfortunately.  I am going to guess they have never worked.  What's odd, is I've seen it out of the box with new servers where we sign in local admin and if I connect removable storage this exact same thing happens (observed with 2 new 2019 servers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions issues appear to have been caused by SentinelOne security software.  The "fix" was to reload the OS.  The damage was unrepairable as far as I know.  I highly advise against using this software!  It will also flood your drive with shadow copies, and in most cases you will be unable to remove the schedule for them.

Comment: Ah, good old SentinelOne... it always creates more problems than it solves.